# Navigation icon not showing up on mobile version?

Tags: html, css, mobile, navigation

So i've modified the css elements to add the **[background image](http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/icon.png)** but so far nothing succeeded in displaying the navigation icon on mobile devices. Please assist me in debuging the code in responsive design view at **[Link](http://www.rosestreetauto.com)** and tell me what worked. thanks for your time.regular css down below

```
#menu-icon {
    display: none;
    background-image: url(http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/icon.png) center;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-image: no-repeat;
}
```

mobile css down below

```
#menu-icon{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`background-image` does not have the multiple properties like position `center`. it should be `background`. Also for repeat syntax should be `background-repeat`. Update your CSS like below.

```
  #menu-icon {
    display: none;
    background: url(http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/icon.png) center;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

Or You can use it like below.

```
  #menu-icon {
    display: none;
    background-image: url(http://www.w3newbie.com/wp-content/uploads/icon.png);
    background-position:center;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
```

Nothing problem in your Mobile CSS.